# How to test If-Modified-Since header is working

Tags: php, http-headers

I have some code that I'd like to test to see if it's properly working. How can I test the if modified since header is working as expected?

```
$headers = getallheaders();
$time = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(filemtime($location), 'Europe/Amsterdam');
$md = md5($time->timestamp);

if(isset($headers['If-Modified-Since'])) {
    $carbon = Carbon::createFromFormat('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $headers['If-Modified-Since'], 'Etc/GMT+0');
    if($carbon->gt($time)) { 
        header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
        exit;
    }
}
if(isset($headers['If-None-Match']) && !Request::isRefresh() && !Request::isPost() && !Request::isAjax()) {
    $trim = trim($headers['If-None-Match']);
    if(($trim == "\"$md\"" || $trim == "$md" || $trim == "'$md'")) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
        exit;
    }
}
$fp = fopen($location, 'rb');
expireHeader();
header("Etag: $md");
header("Content-Type: ".getMimeType($location));
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($location));

fpassthru($fp);
exit;
```

Comment: |Why are you using 3 different timezones in your code?

Comment: @symcbean GMT is the same timezone as london isn't it. And carbon won't recognise the GMT as they are marked as just strings.

Comment: No, London changes between GMT and BST. Even if it didn't you still randomly have Amsterdam in there  :P

Comment: Amsterdam is the timezone my server runs on. I need it for comparing the timestamp on the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a XMLHttpRequest object in your browser and adding your own headers you can test whether a response works correctly or not.

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.addEventListener('load', function() {
   console.log(this.status);
});
xmlhttp.open("get", location.href);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Wed, 16 Mar 2019 13:00:00 GMT");
xmlhttp.send();
```

By modifying the date in the future or the past of the file you're testing you get either a response 200 indicating the file has modified since the given date, or a 304 not modified response.

You could of course write a unit test, but for practicality and to quickly check if the response is what you need it to be this works fine.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more sensible to write your test cases in a language which runs outside a browser / which can be automated?

Comment: Also. creating a question, tagging it as php, then answering your own question using JS doesn't seem too helpful.

Comment: @symcbean Yea of course, but whilst developing I just want to do a quick test if it works, you know to discern which input to use etc... before moving to other things. And since when googling how to to test if the If-modified-since header returns 0 results I decided to post this question and answer for practicalities sake.

Comment: Also, this code isn't testing anything, it's just sending a request and you have to manually, by eye confirm the response in the console?

Comment: @JonStirling Yea, just to fire the request, see if it works, returns the expected outcome. It's not much different than running an unit test, only faster.

Comment: Um... I don't know how you write your unit tests, but I fail to see how this would be faster. I'd much prefer an actual unit test(s) for the PHP code. It's simple, it would run in microseconds and repeatable for automation of tests. Yours is an front-end test which doesn't actually test anything.

Comment: What you described isn't a unit test. That's perhaps why you think it would take a long time. But whatever works for you.